# Why doesn't iLocation based boolean indexing work?

Tags: python, pandas

I was trying to filter a Dataframe and thought that if a `loc` takes a boolean list as an input to filter, it should also work in the case for `iloc`. Eg.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('https://query.data.world/s/jldxidygjltewualzthzkaxtdrkdvq')

df.iloc[[True,False,True]] #works
df.loc[[True,False,True]] #works

df.loc[df['PointsPerGame'] > 10.0] #works
df.iloc[df['PointsPerGame'] > 10.0] # DOES NOT WORK
```

The documentation states that both `loc` and `iloc` accept a boolean array as an argument.

**For iloc**
[image: iloc]

**For loc**
[image: loc]

So, I believe this does not work purely because it was not implemented, or is this because of some other reason which I'm failing to understand?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not [bug](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/17454#issuecomment-327645521):

> this is by-definition not allowed. **.iloc** is purely positional, so it doesn't make sense to align with a passed Series (which is what all indexing operations do).

You need to convert mask to numpy array for `iloc`, for `loc` it working too, but not necessary:

```
df.iloc[(df['PointsPerGame'] > 10.0).values]
```

Comment: Thanks, But if it's 'purely positional', why does it support a Boolean Array as input to filter the rows? eg. `df.iloc[[True,False,True]]`

Comment: @Yankee - For you not working? Because for me working nice `df = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('abc')})` and `print (df.iloc[[True,False,True]])`

Comment: No, it works. My question is, why does this work? Because this is us passing a boolean array as input (and this is not 'purely positional')

Comment: @Yankee - I think because it is list, it not working if pass `Series` - `mask = df['PointsPerGame'] > 10.0` and `print (type(mask))`