# Indexing / slicing methods on data frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I can see that there are 2/3 ways of indexing. iloc, loc and ix (was there in earlier versions, i guess). While experimenting, I found another way that worked. Wanted clarification, why did it worked? Is loc the default method when user doesnt specify anything?

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
```

`iris[iris['species']=="setosa"].head()` and
`iris.loc[iris.species == "setosa"].head()` gives the same result as

```
   sepal_length  sepal_width  petal_length  petal_width species
0           5.1          3.5           1.4          0.2  setosa
1           4.9          3.0           1.4          0.2  setosa
2           4.7          3.2           1.3          0.2  setosa
3           4.6          3.1           1.5          0.2  setosa
4           5.0          3.6           1.4          0.2  setosa
```

I checked iris type is also `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This two give the same result becasue `loc` works with either a Boolean Series or a Boolean array.

So when you give the Boolean Series `(iris['species']=="setosa")`

```
(iris['species']=="setosa")
0       True
1       True
2       True
3       True
4       True
       ...  
145    False
146    False
147    False
148    False
149    False
Name: species, Length: 150, dtype: bool
```

Both (`iris[iris['species']=="setosa"]` and `iris.loc[iris.species == "setosa"]`) are doing a [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing).

While `iloc`, [works only with a Boolean array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59016156/13676202), so, to use `iloc` with the same mask, you can pass the Boolean Series to a numpy array:

```
iris.iloc[(iris['species']=="setosa").values].head()
```